# Model Formset - By Default model formset is rendering one extra field (2 fields in total)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

My model formset without even defining "extra" parameters in modelformset_factory is rendering one extra field in the template. I have tried many variations but it didn't work. If I print the form (the model form) on the command line it just prints a single form field as required but on model formset it prints 2 by default.

Here is my code.

**models.py**

```
class Direction(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Direction|text')
```

**forms.py**

```
class DirectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Direction
        fields = ['text',]
```

**views.py**

```
def myview(request):
    Dirset = modelformset_factory(Direction, form=DirectionForm)
    if request.method == "POST":
        dir_formset = Dirset(request.POST or None)
        if dir_formset.is_valid():
        for direction in dir_formset:
            text = direction.cleaned_data.get('text')
            Direction.objects.create(text=text)
return render(request, "test/test.html", {'DirFormSet':Dirset})
```

**template**

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<div id="forms">
    {{DirFormSet.management_form}}
    {% for form in DirFormSet %}
        {{form.text}}
        {% if error in form.text.errors %}
            {{error|escape}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<button id="add-another">add another</button>

<input type="submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

As a side note, if I submit data on this form it gives the following error.
**Error**

```
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:"u'form-0-id'"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, [`modelformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory) creates one extra form. If you don't want any extra forms, set `extra=0`.

```
Dirset = modelformset_factory(Direction, form=DirectionForm, extra=0)
```

The `KeyError` is because you have not included the form's `id` field in your template. You should have something like:

```
{% for form in dir_formset %}
    {{ form.id }}
    {{ form.text }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Note that you should be passing the formset instance `dir_formset` when rendering the template, not the class `DirFormSet`. Your view should be something like

```
return render(request, "test/test.html", {'dir_formset': dir_formset})
```

then the template should be updated to use `dir_formset` instead of `DirFormSet`.

Comment: I had tried extra=0 before and it worked that but didn't find this in the documentation. Can you refer me to the documentation please. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: The [`modelformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory) docs that I linked to above show that extra defaults to one. See also the docs for regular [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets).

Comment: [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020141/django-formset-raises-keyerror-form-0-id) that I'm having trouble with (and which future readers may find useful)